# How to make token authentication redirect to a url instead of showing an error message in json?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}
```

I need token authentication to redirect to a url instead of showing the error message in json, in case of error 401 Unauthorized:

```
{ 
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need this? DRF endpoints are not supposed to be accessed by the user itself; the front-end application code has to call them.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is catch the status code of the response from the view and redirect
in the case of a get method in a class view:

```
def get(self, request):
    res = super().get(request)
    if res.status_code == 401:
        redirect('somewhere')
```